# Behaviour of a point particle as it falls down a parabolic curve with friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, friction, simulations

(For more details of the mathematics, please see the second answer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4215101/905286)

Suppose I have a curve like $y=x^2$, parametrised as $$\begin{cases}x=\lambda \\y=\lambda^2\end{cases}$$ where $-1 \leq \lambda \leq 1$,

and I drop a point particle from the point (-1, 1) as shown below:
[image]

There **is** friction but there is no rolling.

The resulting path of the ball might look something like this:
[image]

Using the differential equation from the post above, I graphed the time it takes for the purple arc with Python. However, I am not sure if it is correct.

Initially, the kinetic energy is 0 (ball is dropped from rest) and then at the end of the purple arc, just before the ball begins to fall back the other way, the kinetic energy becomes 0 again (ball is instantaneously at rest).

If I graph Kinetic energy vs lambda above and time vs lambda for $\mu = 0.1$ (coefficient of kinetic friction), I get something like this:
[image]

Here is the same graph but with $\mu = 0.5$
[image]

And for $\mu = 1.0$:
[image]

In the graphs above, $t1$ is the time it takes for the ball to complete the purple curve.

I believe kinetic energy becomes negative because the ball starts to go the other way (pink curve) and I need to flip the sign of the friction.

As you can see, $t1$ is lowest for $\mu=0.5$ (at around $0.9687s$), even though my intuition tells me that it should be the lowest for $\mu=1$ since the ball will be stopped fast.

Indeed, if I graph $t1$ for various values of $\mu$, I get a graph like this:
[image]
which suggests that the ball travels for the least time (at least for the purple arc) when $\mu$ is around $0.5$.

**Question**

Why is it that the time is the least for $\mu ≈ 0.5$? It could be that there is a problem with the model/code.